# HashSet in place of ArrayList drawback in performance

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, set

For one of my projects, I was using an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` as a graph data structure.

So the graph:

[image]

will be equivalent to the the list of lists below:

[image]

But I changed my data structure from `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` to `Map<Integer, Set<Integer>>`, so the same graph above will now be equivalent to the map:

[image]

One of the reason I took the choice of `Set` is that every list should contains only unique elements.

The choice of `Map` was for the ease of manipulating the data structure.

The problem is when I changed the data structure, the performance has been down almost by 2x.

Here are the most used operations in my project:

In the first implementation:

```java
int index = someIndex();
int v1 = listoflists.get(index).get(0);
int v2 = listoflists.get(index).get(1);
```

In the second implementation:

```java
int index = somIndex();
Set<Integer> sets = map.get(index);
Integer[] set =  sets.toArray(new Integer[sets.size()]);
int v1 = set[0];
int v2 = set[1];
```

Sometimes I need to get one, two or at most three elements.

Any idea to improve the performance of the second implementation?

Comment: When you fetch the elements from a `Set`, do you perform the same action with all of them?

Comment: why do you translate the set into an array? do you need random access to the elements?

Comment: 1. I am not sure why would someone encouragely represent Graphs as `List<List<Integer>>` or even `Map<Integer, Set<Integer>>`! 2. Since your operations are index-based, making use of a `Set` doesn't make much sense, can you not use a `limit` function and just *3* elements from the `Set` and do whatever further you're doing.

Comment: @SharonBenAsher no, it was my way to get those elements.

Comment: with your first solution you did not enforce uniqueness, and in the 2nd you did. so basically you chnaged the requirements. enforcing uniqueness may come at a price ...

Comment: I suspect that `toArray()` creates a new array and copies all elenments to it (it is really implementation dependant) why not use `iterator()`?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher i will test that.

Comment: I just looked at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray()) and it is quite explicit about the creation of new array and copying etc

Answer (score 1):

```
Integer[] set =  sets.toArray(new Integer[sets.size()]);
```

The above code line is adding extra complexity. Optimize it using an Iterator,

```
int index = somIndex();
Set<Integer> sets = map.get(index);
Iterator iterator = sets.iterator(); 

while (iterator.hasNext()) { 
   System.out.println(iterator.next()); 
}
```

As sometime you require only few values so iterate accordingly.